# Shell script not running

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When I execute the below script, it just sits there with no output.  Any ideas what is wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
for k in `seq 0 4`
do
for c1 in `seq 1 30`
do
for c2 in `seq $c1 30`
do
for b1 in `seq 1 $c1`
do
for b2 in `seq $b1 $c2`
do
for s1 in `seq 0 (($c1 - $b1))`
do
for s2 in `seq 0 (($c2 - $b2))`
do
    echo "k: $k - c1: $c1 - c2: $c2 - b1: $b1 - b2: $b2 - s1: $s1 - s2: $s2"
done
done
done
done
done    
done
done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the `seq` statements is running indefinitely.  You are missing a few dollar signs:

```
for s1 in `seq 0 $(($c1 - $b1))`

for s2 in `seq 0 $(($c2 - $b2))`
```

Comment: @codepk because without the `$` it's a syntax error. Were you suppressing errors?

Comment: @codepk $((...)) will perform arithmetic evaluation and return the actual value; ((...)) without $ will just evaluate the code and set the error value (read the manpage)

Comment: I am new to this.  I thought the $ was for getting value of a variable.  Having $ for a result did not make sense to me.  It's fine now.

Comment: `((...))` only works as a statement, not as an argument to another comand.

Comment: Inside of `(( ))`, it's actually better to use `c1` or `b1` bare, without any `$`.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `seq` here at all; it's pointless.

```
for ((k=0; k<4; k++)); do
  for ((c1=1; c1<30; c1++)); do
    for ((c2=c1; c2<30; c2++)); do
      for ((b1=1; b1<c1; b1++)); do
        for ((b2=b1; b2<c2; b2++)); do
          for ((s1=0; s1<(c1-b1); s1++)); do
            for ((s2=0; s2<(c2-b2); s2++)); do
              echo "k: $k - c1: $c1 - c2: $c2 - b1: $b1 - b2: $b2 - s1: $s1 - s2: $s2"
            done
          done
        done
      done
    done    
  done
done
```

`seq` is an external command that bash has to fork an external process, run, read output from, etc; it involves far more overhead, and isn't even guaranteed to be present (or behave identically) on all operating systems!

By contrast, `(( ))` creates a math context; within such a context, you don't need to use `$` to expand variables, and traditional integer math operators (`<`, `>`, `++`, `--`, etc) are available.

Comment: Might as well use bash sequence expressions for some of those: `for k in {0..4}`

Comment: @Nirk ...for the ones where both values are constants, yes. But there's the question of whether that convenient syntax is a reasonable tradeoff against consistency.

Comment: I was running with sh instead of bash.  Works in bash.